# React native problema para arrancar desde CMD

Tags: react-native

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al intentar arrancar el proyecto de react native desde el CMD me tira este error

Comment: Ya intentaste con: npm install -g expo-cli ??

Comment: sí, pero no funciona

Comment: Intenta eliminar la carpeta node_modules y ejecutar npm install

Answer (score 0):

Pase por ese problema, me paso por que sencillamente tuve problemas al obtener las dependencias que descarga al momento de ejecutar `npm install -g expo-cli`, allí también te muestra que tienes una nueva versión para instalar también. Pero si ya intentaste y te da el error lo mas probable es que alguno de los archivos que tienes instalados este dañado, entonces lo que puedo recomendarte es que uses:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Y luego vuelvas a intentar con `npm install -g expo-cli`.

Otra cosa que puedes intentar si esa no te funciona es ejecutar el comando:

```
npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save
```

Para eliminar la instalación y los posibles archivos dañados, luego volver a ejecutar:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

También recuerda estar en el directorio correcto con el proyecto creado para poder ejecutar el expo start.

Comment: buenas tarde intente de todo elimine node volvi y lo instale y al momento de tirar el comando `npm install -g expo-cli`ya me genera mas errores y si yo andaba en la carpeta y proyectos anteriores me corrían pero con este no se que le pasa

Comment: @KiN-nZiLviN-n estas descargando la Latest version del node? o la LTS?

Comment: al intentar LTS 10.13.0 me genera otro error tambien  genera el mensaje  npm ERR! Invalid or unexpected token                                                                                                                  npm ERR! a complete log of this run can be foun in: @David

Comment: y el log que error te da? debe mandarte un mensaje de error en un txt que es generado cuando eso pasa, podrías mostrar ese error? @KiN-nZiLviN-n